# how to create postback URL for merchant account

Tags: android, android-pay, merchant-account

i am creating a sandbox merchant account, in the wallet for digital goods setting, they are asking for PostBack URL, how do i create a postback url?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postback was the second entry in a search for `postback url` on a popular search engine.

Comment: yes thank you man i already did it but honestly i didn't understand how to do it

Comment: You will have to create a _handler_ that will "wait and listen" for [HTTP POSTs from Google](https://developers.google.com/commerce/wallet/digital/docs/postback). Link is to official documentation and resources/samples that should get you going.